# Which Gmail domain names are available?

Tags: gmail, domain

Am I right, that Google Mail’s default canonical domain name is:

```
googlemail.com
```

and that’s the only one? Are there any country-specific TLDs used?

Comment: But, I believe if I send an email to [username]@googlemail.com, it will reach the inbox of [username]@gmail.com right? Hope someone can clarify this. Cheers~

Comment: Correct. The two domains are functionally identical; mail sent to the same username at either domain will arrive in the same inbox.

Comment: true or not.. this is not an answer to the question.. should be a comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is also [gmail.com](http://www.gmail.com).

See "[googlemail.com domain for certain countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail#googlemail.com_domain_for_certain_countries)" for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of your motivation for asking this, but you may be interested in [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html).  With it, you can use the Gmail software (spam filtering, web interface, etc) on your own domain.  The only cost associated with this is in registering your domain name.  (There are also paid versions of the Google Apps service with more features, but I find the free version sufficient for my family and myself.)